# my jquery always give me the first record only

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i am working on ajax where i get records from server and then filter that record and try to get all emails through a class EMP_EMAIL form that but it gives me only the first one. what i am doing is getting records in from server in one function and display it in side a dialog. as the records i am getting is the record of those employees whose passport is going to expire in 7 days. so i need to send them email and for that purpose i put a button below each employee data in dialog box. now for that purpose i need the emails of every employee with their respective buttons so that email could be send to the right person. so what i am doing is getting records in one function and use another function for email and for that i need all the employee emails from first function and pass it to another function but the problem is that i am unable to get all respective emails but the first one.
as i have the same structure repeated again and again for users with class="EMP_EMAIL".

below is code for it

```
   var employee_email='';
   var flag = false;

   function showCustomer()
   {
  // fire off the request to ajax_stufflist.php
  request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax_stufflist.php?"+url,
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){
        if(data != ''){
    var response = $(data).find("#gmp_stuff").html();
    employee_email=$(response).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").html();
    //alert(employee_email);
    $("#user_responses").html(response);

            $("#user_responses").dialog({
                dialogClass:'transparent',
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,

                width: 1000,
                autoOpen: false,
                overlay: { opacity: 0 }
            });

            $('#user_responses').dialog('open');
            $('#user_responses').css('display','');
            flag = true;
        }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#user_responses").html('error occured');
      }
  });

}

function sendEmail(){
   if(flag)
   {
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "send_email.php?"+employee_email,
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
            $("#email_responses").html();
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
            $("#email_responses").html('error occured');
        }
    });
}
else
    alert('Sending email is unavailable currently. PLease try after some time.');
}
```

this is the input button.

```
 <div class="send_email_notification">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Email" onClick="sendEmail();">
    </div>
```

i tried my best to elaborate my issue but i dont know that i am successed or not but in bottom line i have to get email for all user that are returned after ajax and then when click on the send email button it should sent email to that perticular user.

Comment: Can you post the data that the response variable is holding before you are looking for elements with the class .EMP_EMAIL in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery functions that act as getters (`.val()`, `.html()`, etc without arguments) generally only act on the *first matched element* as a rule. If you want to get the values of all of them you'll need to iterate. There are a few ways you could do this, depending on what exactly you want to do with them afterwards.

The first uses [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(response).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").each(function(i, span) {
    var employee_email = $(span).html(); // can also use this instead of span
    // use employee_email for the current iteration here, it's not visible outside
});
```

The second uses [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to return an array of all of the email addresses:

```
var employee_emails = $(response).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").map(function(i, span) {
    return $(span).html(); // again, could also use this instead of span
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I reviewed your code, The following suggestion may help:

Make sure the showCustomer() function execute before sendEmail() function.      

Eg.

 function sendEmail(){
   showCustomer(); 
   if(flag){....}
 }    


If your want to take email address from browser use .text() instead of .html()

Eg.      

  employee_email = $(response).find(".EMP_EMAIL>span").text();
```

Comment: Please format your answer for better readability. Only the code snippets should be formatted as code.

Comment: Seriously, there's a huge preview of what your post is going to look like *below the input box*. It's not that hard to get it formatted correctly; no spaces at the start of regular text lines, four spaces at the start of code lines.